# Upgrade Magento 2.2 > 2.3.2 - Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\Framework\Communication\Config\Data

Tags: php, magento2

Upon Magento 2 upgrade 2.2.x -> 2.3.2, after running the deployment command `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` I am presented with the following error:

```
......
Module 'Magento_AdvancedPricingImportExport':
Module 'Magento_Directory':
Module 'Magento_Amqp':
Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\Framework\Communication\Config\Data
```

This class exists, and it hasn't been overwritten with a plugin or preference. Why would this core class be throwing an issue?

Answer (score 8):

So I [found this article](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/22773) outlining others stuggle, I feel you all. Thankfully [googla](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/22773#issuecomment-508487348) provided the fix that worked for me, I turned this into a nice module with a preference:

```
<preference for="Magento\Framework\Reflection\TypeProcessor" type="MY\MODULE\Framework\Reflection\TypeProcessor" />
```

Overwriting method `getParamType`:

```
<?php

/**
 * Fix Magento 2.3.2 upgrade setup:upgrade
 * 
 * @see https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/22773 
 * @author Chris Rogers
 * @since 1.0.0 <2019-08-30>
 */

namespace MY\MODULE\Framework\Reflection;

use Magento\Framework\Reflection\TypeProcessor as Original;
use Zend\Code\Reflection\ParameterReflection;
use Zend\Code\Reflection\DocBlock\Tag\ParamTag;


class TypeProcessor extends Original
{
    /**
     * Get the parameter type
     *
     * @param ParameterReflection $param
     * @return string
     * @throws \LogicException
     */
    public function getParamType(ParameterReflection $param)
    {
        $type = $param->detectType();
        if ($type === 'null') {
            throw new \LogicException(sprintf(
                '@param annotation is incorrect for the parameter "%s" in the method "%s:%s".'
                    . ' First declared type should not be null. E.g. string|null',
                $param->getName(),
                $param->getDeclaringClass()->getName(),
                $param->getDeclaringFunction()->name
            ));
        }
        if ($type === 'array') {
            // try to determine class, if it's array of objects
            $paramDocBlock = $this->getParamDocBlockTag($param);
            $paramTypes = $paramDocBlock->getTypes();
            $paramType = array_shift($paramTypes);

            $paramType = $this->resolveFullyQualifiedClassName($param->getDeclaringClass(), $paramType);

            return strpos($paramType, '[]') !== false ? $paramType : "{$paramType}[]";
        }

        return $type;
    }

    /**
     * Gets method's param doc block.
     *
     * @param ParameterReflection $param
     * @return ParamTag
     */
    private function getParamDocBlockTag(ParameterReflection $param): ParamTag
    {
        $docBlock = $param->getDeclaringFunction()
            ->getDocBlock();
        $paramsTag = $docBlock->getTags('param');
        return $paramsTag[$param->getPosition()];
    }
}
```

The main difference is the return:

Original:

> return $this->resolveFullyQualifiedClassName($param->getDeclaringClass(), $type);

Vs:

> return $type;

Victims of Magento, you may continue your daily lives.